# C++ thrift implementation as a class

Tags: c++, boost, thrift

So I'm trying to convert the following C++ thrift server implementation most tutorials give into class form:

```
int port = 9090;
  shared_ptr<SomethingHandler> handler(new SomethingHandler());
  shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new SomethingProcessor(handler));
  shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port));
  shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
  shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

  TSimpleServer server(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory);
```

To do that I made all the shared_ptrs and TSimpleServer members, but I'm running into trouble with initilization assignment.

constructing shared_ptr's in initlization lists seems to result in badmalloc errors, so my workaround was to declare them as members and initialize through asisgnment:

```
 handler = shared_ptr<type>(new Type).
```

The problem here is that TSimpleServer has no assignment operator or constructor taking void, so it needs the shared_ptrs it depends on constructed at constructor time so it can be constructed.
Any thoughts what I am missing here?

More psuedocode:

```
class myclass {
 int port;
 shared_ptr<MyHandlder> handler;
 shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor;
 shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport;
 shared_ptr<TTransportFactory>  transportFactory;
 shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory;
 TSimpleServer server;

  public: 
        explicit myclass(): port(9090), handler(new MyHandler()), processor(new MyProcessor(handler)), serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port)), transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory()), protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory()), server(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory) { }

 int start () { server.serve() }
```

Comment: shared_pointer construction should not result in badmalloc errors. Can you post the constructor initializer code

Comment: perhaps a key relevant component here that I neglected to mention is "myclass" is the thrift server implementation class, ( ie it inherits from a virtual public interface.)   I tried the above code with a different class, and it seemed to work fine...